# Store Date Data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am writing an application that needs to store and analyze users balance in time and also keep the user events in mobile application this has to be done everyday.

What es the best schema design for this? I am confused on how storing this information by day for querying faster after.

**Edit 1**

I have this approaches

1

```
{
    "account": "1q2w3e4r",
    "balances"[
        {
            "date": "2018-11-30",
            "balance": 1234.32
        },
        {
            "date": "2018-12-01",
            "balance": 12.32
        }
    ]
}
```

2

```
{
    "account": "1q2w3e4r",
    "balances": {
         "2018": {
             "01": {"01":1234.32, "02": 422.22, "03": 12353.32, ...},
             "02": {"01":1234.32, "02": 422.22, "03": 12353.32, ...},
             ...
         },
         "2019": {
             "01": {"01":1234.32, "02": 422.22, "03": 12353.32, ...},
             "02": {"01":1234.32, "02": 422.22, "03": 12353.32, ...},
             ...
         }
    }
}
```

Sorry if I'm not explain myself very well, I'm not native speaker and I'm new in mongodb.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are asking.

I have found the online documentation useful:

[mongoosejs.com/docs/guide](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)

I have found it helpful to think about NONSQL data if it were a collection of documents (as opposed to tables, rows, columns in a RDBMS).